# Sweep in matrix operations in R not working as intended

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I am currently trying to efficiently implement a new square matrix, M, as a function of two square matrices of the same dimension, *W* and *V*, as follows: *F<sub>ij</sub>* = *W<sub>ii</sub>·V<sub>ji</sub>*. I.e., the *i*<sup>th</sup> row of *F* is the *i*<sup>th</sup> diagonal element of *W* times the *i*<sup>th</sup> column of *V*.

There is a function in R, `sweep`, that allows one to sweep a statistic across a margin of an array. I.e., doing

```
mean.att <- apply(attitude, 2, mean)
sweep(data.matrix(attitude), 2, mean.att)
```

will de-mean the columns (2<sup>nd</sup> dimension) of the `attitude` matrix (taken from the help). Also, one can supply a function, like `FUN="*"`. In this case, the columns of `attitude` matrix will be *multiplied* by their respective medians.

So the intended code to produce the matrix *F* would be

```
Fij <- matrix(NA, ncol=N, nrow=N)
for (i in 1:N) {
  Fij[i, ] <- w[i, i] * v[, i]
}
```

Apparently, since the forte of R is vectorisation, this can be done with a *sweep* operation: I want to multiply the columns (`FUN="*"`) of *V* by the diagonal of *W*, i.e.

```
Fij2 <- sweep(v, 2, diag(w), FUN="*")
```

However, whenever I check if `Fij==Fij2`, they are not!

MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
w <- matrix(rnorm(16), nrow=4)
v <- matrix(rnorm(16), nrow=4)
Fij <- matrix(NA, ncol=4, nrow=4)
for (i in 1:4) { # This loop can and should be vectorised
  Fij[i, ] <- w[i, i] * v[, i]
}
Fij2 <- sweep(v, 2, diag(w), FUN="*")
Fij
Fij2
```

The diagonal elements are equal, but the off-diagonal ones are not.

I should be very grateful if someone clarified which of the implementations of *F<sub>ij</sub>* is false!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation using sweep gives the transposed result. You can see this easily if you use simpler input matrices:

```
w <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
v <- matrix(5:8, nrow = 2)
Fij <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=2)
for (i in 1:2) {
  Fij[i, ] <- w[i, i] * v[, i]
}
Fij2 <- sweep(v, 2, diag(w), FUN="*")
Fij
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5    6
#> [2,]   28   32
Fij2
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5   28
#> [2,]    6   32
t(Fij2)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5    6
#> [2,]   28   32
```

So `Fij` matches your description, as does `t(Fij2)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Of course, it would be easier to think in terms of *V<sub>ji</sub>* = t(*V<sub>ij</sub>*)! What a slip of attention...

Answer (score 1):

You only forgot to transpose one of the matrices, both implementations are valid:

```
identical(Fij, t(Fij2))
# [1] TRUE
```